# What are the most common sizes I should set my layouts in android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have already developed an android app and is ready for 3.7 inch hdpi phone .But I want the app to work on all types of devices tablets and phones . I have previously developed apps onlyy for fixed sizes . Now I wanted to know for which sizes I should set the layouts differently.(I want the most commonly used sizes)?Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place all the `layouts` with `android:layout_width="fill_Parent"/"wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="fill_Parent"/"wrap_content"` (ofcourse, based on your requirement). Dont hard-code any one of the `layout` parameters and place the below tag in `Manifest` file:

```
 <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: But I have already used hardcoded layouts and the layouts are very complex and using only fill_parent or Wrap_content I cant achieve what I want.

Comment: you can achieve but it takes time. I too first implemented in the way you have done but during maintenance of my project, i re-factored the code and achieved. I am guiding you with my past experiences....:)